# iOS - Push Notification: does it always display a notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios

I'd like to know if it is possible to send a push notification, through **APNS**, without displaying a notification if the application isn't started? (in this case, the message received will be thrown away)

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I am assuming you are asking how to provide the user with options to turn off particular aspects of the push notification?

You will have to set this in the App. That is, if the user wishes to turn off this particular aspect, your App will have to send up the request for them.

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types
```

So, if you still wanted to do badges, but no longer show alerts:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

Don't forget to resend the Token to your provider as it may have changed after this request.