# Can an application receive a push notification while in the background without the user being informed?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I've read the Apple Push Notification documentation and it seems this isn't possible but was just wondering if there are workarounds etc.
If an application is in the background and a server sends a push notification, if there any way the application can receive an inidcation of that fact independently of the user tapping the action button?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this anser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172566/ios-push-notification-does-it-always-display-a-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The application does not get to know about an incoming push notification unless the user activates it with the action button.

Answer (score 0):

No - but if the app is in the background, you can still use the network if you enable multitasking.

With Apple it's always pretty simple: if something is not possible, there won't be workarounds.

Comment: Hi Tom can you clarify this please - I thought background activity was only possible with a UIBackgroundMode of music/gps/voip? Or can request to keep executing in the background for a short while after being sent there but not continuously.

Comment: Then integrate a VOIP client in your app to work around it :) It's definitely a possibility though. If you don't want to do that, consider it impossible.